# Dependency failed for swap, (boots warning at startup)

Tags: boot, swap

After accidentally formatting by windows (I use kali alongside win as dual boot), I entered into grub rescue, and did the usual stuff to recover grub

```
set prefix=(hd0,gpt2)/boot/grub
set root=(hd0,gpt2)
ls /
insmod normal
normal
```

Boot into kali Linux.

Open a Terminal window.

Type the following command and press Enter:

```
update-grub
```

Type the following command and press Enter:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

After that I'v found the swap partition related problem.
I'v used `gparted` to re-create my pre-problem swap partition which is now `/dev/sda8` and set a new uid for it then I `swapon` it and rebooted. But problem remains intact.

Comment: So you have some problem related to the swap partition. But what are the symptoms? Any error messages?

Comment: gave up waiting for suspend/resume device. [time] timed out waiting for device dev-disk-by\x2duuid-.........................dependency failed for /dev/disk/by-uuid/........................... dependency failed for swap